# jcifs - How to copy folder from shared folder to local folder

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, jcifs

I have to copy files and folders from a shared folder to a local folder (linux). I access to the shared folder using SmbFile and I copy the files using InputStream/OutputStream.

I want to copy the folders with their contents too. How can I perform this task? I have to create the folder with FileIO operation and then copy all the subfiles with InputStream/OutputStream or there is another way to copy the folder and the subfiles in one single step?